# Can't install WSL2 on windows 10

Tags: docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have enabled WSL and restarted my PC

[image]

and Installed Ubuntu from windows app store and set the name and password

[image]

I installed Docker but when it starts I get message WSL2 is not installed so I run this command in PowerShell as an Admin but I get an error

```
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature : The request is not supported.
At line:1 char:1
+ Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName $("VirtualMachineP ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature], COMException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Dism.Commands.EnableWindowsOptionalFeatureCommand
```

[image]

I searched and according to this answer https://serverfault.com/questions/337905/enabling-powershell-remoting-access-is-denied#answer-590677 I run this as an admin

```
reg add HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System /v LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
```

and I git a success message. I closed the PowerShell and re-opened as an admin and run the same command again but I got the same error.

How can I install WSL 2 on windows 10 (home edition) to run docker using it not using Hyper-V??

Comment: Is HyperV installed and enabled? I thought that HyperV was a requirement of WSL2

Comment: **Hyper-V is NOT a requirement for WSL2.**  WSL2 can be run on both Windows 10 Professional and Windows 10 Home.  Hyper-V cannot be enabled on Windows 10 Home.  While WSL2 does use hardware virtualization, it does not use Hyper-V specifically, to accomplish that goal.

Comment: @Ramhound Thank you for clarifying. I was mistaken that it required HyperV, but it does apparently require the virtual machine platform. I mistook one for the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to also enable the Virtual Machine Platform in the Windows Features dialog.

[WSL 2 FAQs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl2-faq)

> #### Does WSL 2 use Hyper-V? Will it be available on Windows 10 Home?
>
> WSL 2 is available on all SKUs where WSL is currently available, including Windows 10 Home.
>
> The newest version of WSL uses Hyper-V architecture to enable its virtualization. **This architecture will be available in the 'Virtual Machine Platform' optional component.** This optional component will be available on all SKUs. You can expect to see more details about this experience soon as we get closer to the WSL 2 release.

[image]

In order to get to the above dialog you can simply right-click the **Start** menu and then at the top select **Apps and features**. In there click **Optional features** near the top and then in the next window at the top right you will see **More Windows features**.

---

[image]

---

Then

---

[image]

---

Next

---

[image]

---

And you should now see the dialog above.

Comment: Thanks a lot I really missed it. My bad.

Comment: No worries, we all miss things, especially when requirements change between releases.

Comment: @PHPUser in fact you even *tried* to enable it via the powershell command you used, but I can only assume there was something wrong about the name or command.

Comment: Still didn't work after enabling Virtual Machine Platform, what else is wrong? I just performed a Reset PC after that I can't enable WSL anymore no matter what.